# How to remap fn + ESC key to ESC key in Lenovo Yoga 3

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, lenovo, function-keys

I've managed to switch fn keys to behave like function keys in the Lenovo Yoga.  However, this causes the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to be found to <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> instead.

Is there a way to switch / remap it back to <kbd>ESC</kbd> direct instead?

Comment: Why is there a down rating for a valid question?

Answer (score 3):

The secondary function of the ESC key on this model triggers a special "paper" mode in Windows. This is likely implemented in the machine using an ACPI event sent by the embedded controller, which ends up in the kernel driver and triggers an OS specific action from there.

I have now found the correct event that is generated and sent a patch for Linux-4.4 at https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/7573501/ that solves it on my Yoga 3 11. To clarify, the event is actually done through WMI GUID "26CAB2E5-5CF1-46AE-AAC3-4A12B6BA50E6" rather than the embedded controller, which is why the ideapad-laptop driver could not handle it already.